# Fazer todos os links externos abrir em uma nova guia exceto um!

Tags: javascript, html

Opa, tenho um script que ele identifica todos os links externo e força abrir em nova guia...

```html
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('a').not('[href*="'+document.domain+'"]').attr('target', '_blank');
     $('a').not('[href*="'+document.domain+'"]').attr('rel', 'external nofollow');
 });
 </script>
```

Mas como fazer ele não forçar um domínio..., ou seja.. todos os domínios abrem em nova guia.. menos o do "algumsite.com" ?? ou seja.. só links desse dominio não vai abrir em nova guia.

Tentei fazendo assim:

```html
 <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('a').not('[href*="'+document.domain+'"]').attr('target', '_blank');
   $('a').not('[href*="'+document.domain+'"]').attr('rel', 'external nofollow');
   $('[href*="ads.onlinee.top"]').removeAttr("target");
  });
 </script>
```

**Porem os links de anúncios.. (LINKS EXTERNOS VOLTARAM ABRIR NA MESMA GUIA)**

Comment: Acredito que com regex você consiga fazer isso

Comment: acho que se voce adicionar mais um `.not` voce consegue o resultado.
`$('a').not('[href*="'+document.domain+'"]').not('[href*="algumsite.com"]').attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: esse algumsite.com tem que abrir na mesma pagina!

Comment: Testei esse ai, não funcionou!

Comment: Todos do mesmo domínio ou ["algum.com", "outrotambem.com"] devem abrir na mesma página?

Comment: Todos do dominio "site01.com" abre na mesma guia... outros domínios externos.. abrem em nova guia..

Comment: No codigo que coloquei acima ele estava colocando **target** para os elementos **a** cujo **href** não tinha o **dominio atual** e **algumsite.com**. Pode ser que o seu link já tenha o `target='_blank'`, nesse caso voce precisa remover o `target`. Voce pode selecionar ele e remover com o seguinte codigo `$('[href*="algumsite.com"]').removeAttr("target")`.   [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: Coloquei outro... porem ele os outros parou de funcionar..

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta minha tentativa... adicionado seu código..

Comment: Adiciona também o html, de como estão declarados os `<a href="">`

Comment: como assim ? como coloco ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu usei isso:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("a[href^=http]").each(function(){

      // NEW - excluded domains list
      var excludes = [
         'excludeddomain1.com',
         'excludeddomain2.com',
         'excluded.subdomain.com'
      ];
      for(i=0; i<excludes.length; i++) {
         if(this.href.indexOf(excludes[i]) != -1) {
            return true; // continue each() with next link
         }
      }

      if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {

           // attach a do-nothing event handler to ensure we can 'trigger' a click on this link
           $(this).click(function() { return true; }); 

           $(this).attr({
               target: "_blank",
               title: "Opens in a new window"
           });

           $(this).click(); // trigger it
      }
   })
});
```

Comment: valeu, deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

**Esse funciona**

```
   $("a[href^=http]").each(function(){

      // domínio excluído (mesma janela)
      var excludes = [
         'dominio.com'
         ];

         if(this.href.indexOf(excludes) != -1) {
            return true;
         }

      if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {

           $(this).click(function() { return true; }); 

           $(this).attr({
               target: "_blank"
           });

           $(this).click();
      }
   })
});
```

Caso queira inserir uma lista:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("a[href^=http]").each(function(){

      // NEW - excluded domains list
      var excludes = [
         'excludeddomain1.com',
         'excludeddomain2.com',
         'excluded.subdomain.com'
      ];
      for(i=0; i<excludes.length; i++) {
         if(this.href.indexOf(excludes[i]) != -1) {
            return true; // continue each() with next link
         }
      }

      if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {

           // attach a do-nothing event handler to ensure we can 'trigger' a click on this link
           $(this).click(function() { return true; }); 

           $(this).attr({
               target: "_blank",
               title: "Opens in a new window"
           });

           $(this).click(); // trigger it
      }
   })
});
```

[**Fonte** - techfoobar - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071254/open-all-external-links-open-in-a-new-tab-apart-from-a-domain/12071371#12071371)